# How to list files of a mega.nz folder using python 3.9.1?

Tags: python

I only found this:

```
m = mega.login('email', 'password')

files = m.get_files()
extracted = []
for file in files:
   extracted.append(files[file]['a']['n'])
```

it returns all of the files and folders:

```
['Cloud Drive', 'Inbox', 'Rubbish Bin', 'Welcome to MEGA.pdf', 'FolderN1', 'balloon.png', 'FolderN1/subfolder/balloon.png', 'subfolder', etc. ]
```

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: How to list files of a mega.nz folder using python 3.9.1?

Answer (score 0):

if (files[x]['t'] == 0) it is file.

```
files = m.get_files()
extracted = []
for x in files:
  if files[x]['t'] == 0:
     extracted.append(files[x]['a']['n'])
```

example results:

```
['video.zip', 'film.mkv', 'legal_data.zip', 'tools.py', 'upload.py', 'learn.pdf']
```